# What is wrong with this script fragment?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

Getting the validation error: `Error: an attribute specification must start with a name or name token` but I can't fault it, I think it needs fresh eyes!!

The script is located within `<script>` tags on a PHP page, so the php is executing just fine.

```
var Target = ' target="_blank"';
    var twtTitle  = "I am going to <?php echo $fb_title;?>";

var tinyUrl = "<?php 

        echo getTinyUrl(curPageURL());?>";

document.write('<a class="twitter" href="'+twtLink+'"'+Target+'><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/style/images/social/twitter.png"  border="0" alt="Tweet This!" /> <span class="link_text"> Tweet this event</span></a>');
```

Here are all the vars as rendered by the server (post PHP)

```
    var Target = ' target="_blank"';
    var twtTitle  = "I am going to Teenage 16-19";

    var tinyUrl = "http://tinyurl.com/6eem8qc";

    var twtLink =  'http://twitter.com/home?status='+encodeURIComponent(twtTitle + ' ' + tinyUrl + " via @WaggleB"+ "");
```

Adding an alert to show the value of `twtLink` shows the value as

```
http://twitter.com/home?status=I%20am%20going%20to%20Teenage%2016-19%20http%3A%2F%2Ftinyurl.com%2F6eem8qc%20via%20%40WaggleB
```

Comment: What's the value of `twtLink` ?

Comment: I have edited the question to be clearer

Comment: I have now included the value of twtLink at the bottom of the question

Comment: Could it be that your twtTitle contains a single quote (I'm)? This mix of single and double quote is confusing.

Comment: I spotted that, but changed it to `I am` but still the same problem. It seems to have issue with the double quote to close my href, but I have no idea why!!

Comment: Do you get the error if you change a variable, like `twtLink="nothing"`? all variables? You got to find _where_ exactly is the error is coming from first.

Comment: Clearly this question is not going to get answered, and is too specific. Voted to close.

Answer (score 1):

You did not close href attribute with a quotation mark properly.

http://validator.w3.org/docs/errors.html

EDIT AFTER QUESTION UPDATE

This also looks extremely suspicious:

```
'><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/style/images/social/twitter.png"  border="0" alt="Tweet This!" /> <span class="link_text"> Tweet this event</span></a>'
```

Specifically, variable template_url that appears to be between single quotation marks inside another pair of single quotation marks.

Comment: It's PHP, and it fires correctly. The javascript (or validation checker) can't see those quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing your script in `<![CDATA[` and `]]>` blocks. Depending on your doctype, you might have an issue with javascript strings containing html tags if it's not in a cdata block.